# Performing Sticky load balancing in Camel

Tags: soap, xpath, load-balancing, apache-camel

Hi I would like to perform sticky load balncing in apache camel based on the SOAP session, whcih is embedded in ServiceGroupID node of the first response.

I wrote a small route as follow:

```
from(uri)
.loadBalance().sticky(xpath(query).namespaces(env).namespaces(wsa).namespaces(ax))
.to(BE1,BE2);
```

Where URI is the string to which the requests are passed and BE1 and BE2 are the two backend servers.

And my query is

```
String query = "/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/wsa:ReplyTo/wsa:ReferenceParameters/axis2:ServiceGroupId/text()";
```

If i am not wrong this query would extract the servicegroupID from my SOAP header.

But when I try to perform the balancing, due to some reason whatsoever, the requets are not being passed to the same backend server.

and my env, wsa and ax are the namespaces, which are :

```
Namespaces env = new Namespaces("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
Namespaces wsa = new Namespaces("wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
Namespaces ax = new Namespaces("axis2", "http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2");
```

Am I doing something wrong here?
If so what? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Also being discussed at the mailing list
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Performing-Sticky-load-balancing-in-Camel-tp5719170.html

Please dont start the same topic in multiple places at the same time. And if you do, then at least tell us, so we would know this.

People get upset when they spend time to help you, when its already been answered in another place!

Comment: I am extremely sorry, But I usually start multiple topic at different places simultaneously! I wouldn't do that next time.